# Trying to set a custom font to each individual ListAdapter button

Tags: java, android, listview, listadapter

I have a list adapter and im using `holder.text.setTypeface(TYPEFACE)` to set the type face and I have a string of names that im using assign each `ListView` button its text. But im wondering how to set just one individual list item a custom font. Basically say I have the 3 ListAdapter buttons, Button 1, Button 2, and Button 3. I want Button 2 to be a custom font while Button 1 and Button 3 Stay regular. How can this be done?

Comment: i did not understood the questoin you want to customize items font on your textview according to a set of buttons outside the listview? can you share some code how are you doing it now?, or write a clearer question...?

Answer (score 9):

Create class that extends ArrayAdapter and set the font in the getView procedure.

Comment: Or any other ListAdapter such as ArrayAdapter, BaseAdapter, CursorAdapter, SimpleAdapter...

Comment: And you can have some sort of check in this method to see which button it is (based on the button's id), so you can just check if you want to change the text.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to do this my favorite two are to set it in the XML layout. This will work if the same custom font is desired on every "Button2" and if the `Typeface` you want is already part of the system.

```
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:typeface="sans" />
```

The second way to do this is to customize a ListAdapter with a `ViewBinder`.  As Pinassi wrote, it is possible to do from `getView()` however this has the drawback of not being able to easily see data and mixes generic UI code with custom UI code.  Both [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) and [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) have an inner class named `ViewBinder` with method `setViewValue`. Each signature is different because of the underlying data it manages.

Simply override `setViewValue` for only the customization you want to manually control. For example is `R.id.button1` is a simple text binding just have the method return false and the API will handle it for you but since we're customizing `R.id.button2` we will return true.

```
switch(v.getId){
case R.id.button2:
   TextView button2 = (TextView) v;
   button2.setTypeface(customTypeFace);
   // bind text here or return false to allow the API to do this for you.
break;
// other customization
}
```

`customTypeFace` comes from a system [Typeface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html) or the project's [assets folder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#createFromAsset%28android.content.res.AssetManager,%20java.lang.String%29). Android uses TrueType Fonts.